# OpenFeint integration on iOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, openfeint

I am trying to integrate OpenFeint 2.12.5 into my app. I already read [this tutorial](http://pocketworx.com/?p=80) and [this one](http://hacker-pro.com/forum/index.php?topic=1658.0).. I read the [Getting Started](http://support.openfeint.com/dev/readme-for-openfeint-ios-sdk-2-12-5/) page in documentation and follow their indications.

I am using xcode 4.2 whit iOS 5.0 and 2.12.5 framework version of OF; tried to clean, rebuild, RECOMPILE whole thing, nothing works. I get several errors, like:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'OFLog'
```

and

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'OFDelegate'
```

and

```
'OpenFeint/OpenFeint.h' file not found
```

and a warning on `[OpenFeint applicationWillResignActive];`
like:

```
Class method '+applicationWillResignActive' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

Can someone help me or indicate a tutorial or something??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: [openfeint-with-sparrow](http://forum.sparrow-framework.org/topic/tutorial-integrating-openfeint-with-sparrow)

Answer (score 1):

openfeint changed significantly a few months ago - looks like those tutorials are referencing the old version. for example, there is no `[OpenFeint applicationWillResignActive]` anymore. in the past you integrated OF by dragging all the OF source into your project, but now the preferred way is via including the OF framework.

i'd recommend starting the integration over and using only the official OpenFeint documentation as a reference.

Comment: thanks! has I said, I'm doing that, whit no luck.. :(
I tried including the framework and including the files.
It keeps giving me strange errors.. thanks anyway

Comment: but  `+(void)launchDashboardWithHighscorePage:(NSString*)leaderboardId;` still exists and I have a warning: `Class method '+launchDashboardWithHighscorePage: not found (return type defaults to 'id')`